# Google BigQuery export with single wildcard URI

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, sharding

I am currently trying to export the daily Google Analytics data (automatically linked from GA with daily cadence) in BigQuery to buckets created in Google Cloud Storage.

When I export the daily GA table in BigQuery to GCS with single wildcard URI, it automatically splits the table into multiple sharded files (around 1gb per file) and land in the designated buckets in GCS. But when I copy the daily GA table to a manually created table in BigQuery, exporting the manually created table to GCS resulted in more sharded files (around 300mb per file), even though they have the same size and row counts.

I am trying to figure out why exporting this manually created table would cause BigQuery to shard the table this way. Essentially this would tripled the amount of files sitting in GCS. Ideally I would like to limit the amount of the sharded files in GCS so I do not need to process so many of them.

Comment: Not sure why BigQuery shards differently for each scenario. Still I wonder why having more files could be a problem for you. Usually this is how you want to work with data exported from BQ, several small files tends to be better then a few bigger files (as it's easier to parallelize  jobs operations).

Comment: @WillianFuks

Thank you for your comment Willian. Because the Python API in GCS doesn't have the capability to drop the entire bucket, which means my code needs to loop through each shard files and delete them one by one. 

Some of these buckets could end up being more than 700 shard files. You could imaging how long the GCS delete would take.

Comment: The Python API indeed [refuses to delete](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/storage/google/cloud/storage/bucket.py#L418) buckets with more than 256 files. One workaround might be to run a gs call command in python. You could also start an [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/new) in python's repository discussing about that.